# Has anyone ever worked on a OR problem like this before?

Tags: optimization

Here is the situation (it's a silly example just to illustrate the point):

A computer repair company is primarily focused on repairing computers. However, the company has recently become interested in estimating the profits they will earn by repairing computers (e.g. let's assume that the company has no idea how much money they will actually have to spend repairing a computer until they are finished - thus, they want to predict the profit in advance before negotiating with the customer). They decide that for a given computer, the profits can be estimated by measuring three variables associated with each computer: X1, X2, X3. Thus, the general form of the model can be expressed as:

Profits = f(X1, X2, X3)

For this example, let's say that the company has 3 labs. The first lab is made of junior employees, the second lab is made of intermediate employees and the third lab is made of senior employees. Let's assume that employees from the third lab are on average "better at measuring X1, X2, X3" than employees from the second lab, and employees from the second lab are better than employees from the first lab. The first lab is the biggest lab, the second lab is smaller, and the third lab is the smallest.

So for the same computer : an employee from the first lab might measure a value of X1, but an employee from the second lab might measure a different value of X1 for the same computer. Theoretically, it is also possible that an employee from the third lab might measure the same value of X1 as the employee from the second lab.

When the company receives computers from their customers, they are generally first sent to the first lab. From here, the computers have their values of X1, X2, X3 measured, then repaired, and then sent back to customer - OR - the computers are sent to the second lab (e.g. if the junior employees don't know how to fix it), where their values of X1, X2, X3 are re-measured, repaired and sent back to the customer - OR - sent to the third lab, X1, X2, X3 remeasured, repaired and sent back to the customer.

The company is interested in getting the computers back to the customers - they are not as interested in recording the more accurate measurements for X1, X2, X3 for each computer (e.g. if the junior employees from the first lab can fix the computer, the company will not waste time sending the computer to the third lab just to record a better set of measurements). For each repaired computer, the company also tracks the profits they made.

Question: Now, let's assume these two scenarios for modelling

Scenario 1: Suppose for any given computer, the company only keeps the last set of measurements for X1, X2, X3, because they believe that these are the most accurate set of measurements. But the company wants to make their predictions on incoming computers as early on as possible, i.e. based on measurements taken from the first lab**. This is creating a "mismatch"** : a statistical model created using the available data contains measurements of different quality. When the first lab will make measurements for a computer, it's likely that they might be somewhat incorrect and likely to change. Are there any statistical models that can be used in this scenario? Is this an example of "measurement error" models?

Scenario 2: Suppose now the company decides to keep all measurements made for each computer. This means that some computers might have 3 measurements (lab 1 : X1. X2, X3), some computers might have 6 measurements (lab 1 : X1, X2, X3 AND lab 2: X1, X2, X3) and computers might have 9 measurements (lab 1: X1, X2, X3 AND lab 2: X1, X2, X3 AND lab 3: X1, X2, X3). However, the company always wants to make predictions for new predictions based on the measurement taken at the first lab. This now looking like a longitudinal/repeated measures problem - but I am still not sure.

I am not sure how to make models for scenario 1 and scenario 2. I know that in this problem, it would be reasonable to believe that more complicated computers get sent to lab 3 - thus, try to cluster the data and make separate models based on how complex the computers are. But imagine if we had no way of knowing which computers will receive 3 measurements or which will receive 9 measurements.

At this point, I am thinking of just giving up and creating a model that uses the data from the most recent lab - and just hoping that the differences in measurements between the first lab, second lab and third lab are negligible (and make models using the most recent data) ..... Or try and make layered hypothesis tests : take computers that reached lab 2 and compare the updates in measurements between lab 1 THEN take computers that reached lab 3 and compare the updates in measurements between lab 2 and lab 1, etc.). But in the real world, there could be thousands of "points" (i.e. "labs") in which the observed data can get updated before it stabilizes).

Has anyone worked on such kinds of problems?

Comment: Before i reply or invest any effort in this question can you go back to your car repair shop question and actually award one of the two answers there a green check mark?
It would be also good if you more clearly seperate this question from your car repair shop one.

Comment: my apologies, I had thought I had rewarded the answer from the previous question

Comment: in car repair shop, there is only one repair shop and one set of measurements for each car. in this new question, it is possible that observations might have different number of measurements with different levels of precision

Comment: Whatever scheme you can come up with, you really want to compare the performance of your different implementations using a synthetic cost function with synthetic  service level appropriate noise added on the true X1, X2, X3 and see how these approaches perform. In fact i would code up all models and just see which performs most robustly or converges faster

Comment: Can you assume that all measurement errors are normally distributed and just the variance differs? Do you even have an idea about the distribution of measurement errors? Have you considered just calculating the expectation value given a certain measurement and a certain level of precision and try to fit that against the actual cost?